# JS - passing by reference an object

Tags: javascript

Given the code below I create an object called foo and I want to make 'a' equal to true from my function called maketrue(obj).

```
var foo = {a: false, b: false, c: false}

 function maketrue(obj)
 {
 obj = true;    
 }

 maketrue(foo.a); // I want to make 'a' true from the function

 console.log(foo.a);
```

Why does it return false still?

I have looked at similar questions that worked passing an object but my method doesn't pass by reference.

Comment: You're not passing an object, you're passing `false`. Javacript does not have pass-by-reference.

Comment: try passing `foo` as argument, then set `foo.a` to true inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the object as an argument (that would be passed by reference), you're passing in only the boolean value of the object's property (pass by value).

If you want something like this would work:

```
 var foo = {a: false, b: false, c: false}

 function maketrue(obj, val)
 {
 obj[val] = true;    
 }

 maketrue(foo, 'a'); // I want to make 'a' true from the function

 console.log(foo.a);
```

Comment: Objects aren't passed by reference either. They do however consist of references to their properties.

Comment: Don't confuse *pass-**by**-reference* with *passing **a** reference*. Variables store references *to* objects and it's those references that are passed around. However, that has nothing to do with *pass-by-reference*, which describes a technique how callers pass values to callees. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the additional clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript objects are represented as references. foo.a is not an object, foo however, is. Try this:

```
 var foo = {a: false, b: false, c: false}

 function maketrue(obj)
 {
 obj.a = true;    
 }

 maketrue(foo);

 console.log(foo.a);
```

Comment: *"In JavaScript objects are passed by reference."* No. Objects are *represented as* references. That has nothing to do with *pass-**by**-reference* though. JavaScript is strictly pass by value. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy for more info.

Comment: My bad, I changed my answer appropriately. That's the reason you can't reassign the object directly inside the function, isn't it?

Comment: Yep. If JavaScript was pass-by-reference we could do something like `var foo = 42; var bar = foo; bar = 21;` and `foo` would be `21` as well. This is completely independent of the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
var foo = {a: false, b: false, c: false}

 function maketrue(obj)
 {
 obj.a = true;    
 }

 maketrue(foo);

 console.log(foo.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with **Object** and **Properties** in Javascript:

```
var foo = {a: false, b:false, c:false}    

/**
 * Way Object
 */
function maketrue(obj)
{   
    obj.a = true;  // Specific property
}
maketrue(foo);

/**
 * Way Property
 */
function maketrue(obj, prop)
{   
    obj[prop] = true;  // property as a parameter
}
maketrue(foo, 'a');

console.log(foo.a);
```